# Using aliases in distance calculation

Tags: mysql

I've got 2 tables: candidate and `candidate_location`. The `candidate_location` table gets map coordinates from either of 3 other tables depending on it's `type` field. The result are the aliases `lat` and `lng` which need to be used in the part of the query following the IF statements where it works out the distance.

I'm getting the error that it can't find the "lat" or "lng" column in the distance calculation part, I guess because they are aliases. How could I restructure this so they are recognised in the calculation?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT candidate.CandID,
    IF (candidate_location.type = 1, p.latitude, IF (candidate_location.type = 2, a.latitude, pr.latitude)) AS lat,
    IF (candidate_location.type = 1, p.longitude, IF (candidate_location.type = 2, a.longitude, pr.longitude)) AS lng,
    IF (candidate_location.type = 2, a.standard_deviation,null) as standard_deviation, 
   ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.41019) ) * cos( radians(lat ) ) 
   * cos( radians(lng) - radians(0.07222)) + sin(radians(51.41019)) 
   * sin( radians(lat)))) AS distance 

    FROM candidate_location

    LEFT JOIN geo_postcodes AS p ON (candidate_location.type = 1 AND candidate_location.postal_id  = p.id) 
    LEFT JOIN geo_area_averages AS a ON (candidate_location.type = 2 AND candidate_location.postal_id  = a.id)
    LEFT JOIN geo_probability AS pr ON (candidate_location.type = 3 AND candidate_location.postal_id  = pr.id) 
LEFT JOIN candidate ON candidate_location.candid=candidate.CandID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ashwin mentioned, you can not use the result column name directly as a field in computation.  You would need to restate it again... unless you alternatively use MySql variables.  They work like inline programming.  Set the variable value, then use that, but you can still retain that value AS the column name in question.

```
SELECT 
      candidate.CandID,
      @varLat := COALESCE( p.latitude, a.latitude, pr.latitude) AS lat,
      @varLong := COALESCE( p.longitude, a.longitude, pr.longitude) AS lng,
      COALESCE( a.standard_deviation, null) as standard_deviation, 
      ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.41019) ) * cos( radians(@varLat ) ) 
         * cos( radians(@varLat) - radians(0.07222)) + sin(radians(51.41019)) 
         * sin( radians(@varLong)))) AS distance
   FROM 
      ( select @varLat := 0.00, @varLong := 0.00) sqlvars,
      candidate_location CanLoc
         LEFT JOIN geo_postcodes AS p 
            ON (CanLoc.type = 1 AND CanLoc.postal_id  = p.id) 
         LEFT JOIN geo_area_averages AS a 
            ON (CanLoc.type = 2 AND CanLoc.postal_id  = a.id)
         LEFT JOIN geo_probability AS pr 
            ON (CanLoc.type = 3 AND CanLoc.postal_id  = pr.id) 
         LEFT JOIN candidate 
            ON CanLoc.candid=candidate.CandID
```

Also, I am using COALESCE() instead of nested IF() blocks.  The first non-null value is returned, so since your joins are based on the type 1, 2 or 3, only that row will have a value to qualify.

Comment: @dlofrodloh, I missed one of the Lat references... check the revision.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've never used this method before and it could prove quite useful, it also seems to work much faster than the other valid solution

Answer (score 2):

You're defining aliases in the same query that's using them. Try taking the distance clause outside the main query so you can use lat and lng from a sub-query as follows:

```
Select tTable.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.41019) ) * cos( radians(lat ) ) 
* cos( radians(lng) - radians(0.07222)) + sin(radians(51.41019)) 
* sin( radians(lat)))) AS distance 
from (
SELECT candidate.CandID,
IF (candidate_location.type = 1, p.latitude, IF (candidate_location.type = 2, a.latitude, pr.latitude)) AS lat,
IF (candidate_location.type = 1, p.longitude, IF (candidate_location.type = 2, a.longitude, pr.longitude)) AS lng
IF (candidate_location.type = 2, a.standard_deviation,null) as standard_deviation  

FROM candidate_location

LEFT JOIN geo_postcodes AS p ON (candidate_location.type = 1 AND candidate_location.postal_id  = p.id) 
LEFT JOIN geo_area_averages AS a ON (candidate_location.type = 2 AND candidate_location.postal_id  = a.id)
LEFT JOIN geo_probability AS pr ON (candidate_location.type = 3 AND candidate_location.postal_id  = pr.id) 
LEFT JOIN candidate ON candidate_location.candid=candidate.CandID ) tTable
```

Comment: Thanks, this method also works well, however the other answer is much faster in execution time so I chose that one

Comment: That's true. It's a better solution.